# Permitan o permiten resignificar

Tags: gramática

¿Por qué es "permitan" en vez de "permiten" en el siguiente párrafo? ¿Será porque hay posibilidad que la resignificación no funcione? El párrafo lo encontré en Facebook. ¡Muchas gracias!

"En esta sesion se hablará de
restablecer y replantear vínculos emocionales que permitan resignificar el dolor de la pérdida."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los vínculos son vínculos genéricos, no específicos. Entonces usamos el subjuntivo

> Estoy buscando a alguien que me limpie los zapatos
> Conozco a alguien que me limpia los zapatos

> No hay obstáculo que no se pueda vencer
> Este es un obstáculo que no se puede vencer

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta. ¿Podría Usted dar unos ejemplos de comparación entre vínculos genéricos y vínculos específicos en este caso? ¡Muchísimas gracias otra vez!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Maurice, no es necesario poner mayúscula en el pronombre *Usted*, pues no inicia la frase. Que estés bien

Comment: Ah, ¡vale! Muchas gracias, VeAqui ~