# Una comparación entre vínculos genéricos en que se usa el subjuntivo y vínculos específicos en que se usa el indicativo

Tags: gramática

¿Podría alguien dar unos ejemplos de comparación entre vínculos genéricos en que se usa el subjuntivo y vínculos específicos en que se usa el indicativo basados en este [enlace](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42025/permitan-o-permiten-resignificar/42026#42026)? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No me queda claro a qué se refiere el usuario con "vínculos genéricos" y "vínculos específicos".

Comment: No sé si mdewey podría ayudar ...

Comment: En el enlace, mdewey ha escrito dos ejemplos. Está buscando otro tipo de ejemplos?

Comment: Los dos ejemplos fueron añadidos después de que yo hubiera publicado esta pregunta, quizás por RubioRic. Y no hace falta dar ejemplos adicionales en este caso. ¡Muchísimas gracias a Ustedes!